# Could Brent Spiner still play Data?

Tags: star-trek

We're now 10 years on from the last Star Trek film that effectively killed the TNG franchise, but even then the timeless android was showing small signs of age.

Having said that, the the make-up of the character is such that it would cover a lot of... imperfections, and a suitable hair piece is no problem.

Even though the older treks are dead, do you think Brent Spiner could convincingly be re-made up as the character? Brent is looking seriously old now.

Comment: Thanks to technology, anything is possible. Look at TRON Legacy.

Comment: Hmmm yes. For the purposes of this question, let's assume CGI is out.

Comment: Are you looking for a purely technical answer, i.e. make-up techniques?

Comment: VTC. "Do you think..." is clearly asking for opinions, not verifiable facts.

Comment: "Do you think" isn't necessarily a clear indication of opinion. If you asked me "Do you think you could build a deck of a x b dimensions with this amount of lumber in this style" that isn't soliciting opinion, but calculation plus some knowledge.

Comment: Why is CGI out? If I look at films like _Terminator Salvation_, I'd say we're not that far off from creating a credible android through computer.

Comment: It's just a 1 line fix in the script. "Thank G-d Data invented the whatever-chip to allow himself to appear to age so that he doesn't make the rest of us feel old".

Answer (score 8):

The physical age of the actor would be one of the easiest things for the ST writers to salvage. *Especially* since we are talking about Data, an Android who has the distinct goal of becoming more human, a condition that inherently comes at the price of mortality and ageing. Similarly to [The Bicentennial Man](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Bicentennial_Man), it could be convincingly explained that Data had willingly modified himself to age and eventually die, just as an actual human would.

In fact, he took comfort in learning of his mortality in [Time's Arrow](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Time%27s_Arrow_%28episode%29) even though it was later discovered that the assumption that he died in that cave was incorrect (time travel timey-wimey).

Regarding writing, the writers of a potential TNG film would probably briefly [lampshade](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging) his physical appearance and move on with the story. In addition, CGI could help in drastically reducing the effects.

**Yes, Spiner *could* still convincingly portray Lt. Cmdr. Data despite his age.**

Comment: Quite true. In fact, in the future scenario shown in "All Good Things...", we saw that Data had tinted his hair gray; he felt it added "an air of distinction".

Answer (score 5):

No (if CGI is out). They specifically killed off Data because **Brent** did NOT want to continue playing.

> *when Spiner was asked if he thought Data could come back he said:*
>
> I don’t think that could happen. Look at me. I am a shockingly older gentleman. I don’t see that I could wear that makeup anymore. I think that would look really stupid. I love the character and I wish I started it much younger, but I was already in my mid sixties when I started [joke]. I just don’t think I could get away with it. Yeah they could CGI it, but why not just CGI the whole character and forget about me. ([src](http://trekmovie.com/2011/06/29/brent-spiner-talks-typcasting-death-of-data-bringing-back-soong-for-star-trek-sequel/))

Comment: It's less about if he wants to, and more if he physically could.

Comment: They kinda left the door open, didn't they? Data was killed but he could be returned at will as his memories and personality traits were preserved in [B-4](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/B-4).

Comment: @monkeymatrix = " I don’t see that I could wear that makeup anymore.". Yes, you can put a gun to his head and make him wear the makeup (which IIRC was negatively affecting his health). I don't think that's a valid answer.

Comment: @monkeymatrix: Then the answer is yes. But he won't do it.

Comment: @Voldemort if they gave him the chance and sufficient money I'm sure he'd be thrilled to do it. He was just acknowledging that he's too old, from the perspective of the franchise and the audience.